# windows iterate thru files in directory in batch file return error

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am creating a .bat file that iterates thru files in a specific directory. Here it is the part of the code that does this:

```
@echo off

 setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

 set DSPath=C:\Axway_DS
 set inFolder=!DSPath!\Datastore\getStarted\withDatastore\data
 set fileToTreat=!inFolder!\
 set outFolder=C:\Users\acucu\Desktop\folders\exit\arn\out
 set DSRuntime=!DSPath!\Datastore\DatastoreRuntime
 set archive=C:\Users\acucu\Desktop\folders\exit\arn\archive

 set fileIn=deleteInput.txt
 set logSuppresion=supp.log
 set logMaintenance=maintenance.log
 set fichierTrace=!outFolder!\TRSUPIN.txt
 set case=SUPPRESSION

 for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%c%%a%%b)
 set mytime=%time%
 set mytime2=%time::=%
 set mytime2=%mytime2:.=%

cd !folderIn!
for %%i in (*) do ( 
echo Am intrat
set fileIn=%%i
set COUNTER=0
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (!fileIn!) do (

set /A COUNTER+=1

  set countRows=0   
  set idInjection=%%a

      ......................

)
)

endlocal
```

The problem appears here:

```
 C:\Users\acucu\Desktop\folders\exit\arn>cd !folderIn!
 The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

And the execution stops.
What am I doing wrong?
Now I'm getting the same error on an older version which was working last time I checked:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set DSPath=C:\Axway_DS
set inFolder=!DSPath!\Datastore\getStarted\withDatastore\data
set fileToTreat=!inFolder!\
set outFolder=C:\Users\acucu\Desktop\folders\exit\arn\out
set DSRuntime=!DSPath!\Datastore\DatastoreRuntime
set archive=C:\Users\acucu\Desktop\folders\exit\arn\archive

set fileIn=deleteInput.txt
set logSuppresion=supp.log
set logMaintenance=maintenance.log
set fichierTrace=!outFolder!\TRSUPIN.txt
set case=SUPPRESSION

for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%c%%a%%b)
set mytime=%time%
set mytime2=%time::=%
set mytime2=%mytime2:.=%
set COUNTER=0

  for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (!fileIn!) do (

set /A COUNTER+=1

set countRows=0 
set idInjection=%%a

::Suppresion de l'injection
call !DSRuntime!\dstools deleteCollection -i %%a > !logSuppresion!_!COUNTER! 2>&1

IF !errorlevel!==0 (
    set result=OK 
    set comm= 
    ) ELSE (
     set result=KO
        for /f "delims=" %%x in (!logSuppresion!_!COUNTER!) do (
        set "comm=%%x"  )
        )


 call !DSRuntime!\dstools.bat maintenance -tasks CLEAN_COLLECTION > !logMaintenance!_!COUNTER!
    set /a count=0
    for /f "tokens=3 delims=:" %%i in ('find "Deleted row(s) count:" !logMaintenance!_!COUNTER!') do set /a count=%%i

    set countRows=!count!   


     ::Creation des dossiers s'ils n'existent pas
     if not exist !outFolder! mkdir !outFolder!
     if not exist %archive% mkdir %archive!%            

    ::Alimentation des variables avec des blancs  
    set countRows=!countRows!                  
    set fileIn=!fileIn!                                                                     
    set idInjection=!idInjection!                                                  
    set comm=!comm!                                                                                                    

    ::Creation du fichier de trace d'accompagnement
    if exist !fichierTrace! set            fichierTrace=!outFolder!\TRSUPIN_!mydate!_!mytime2!.txt 


    echo. 2>!fichierTrace!
    echo !case:~0,11!!countRows:~0,18!!fileIn:~0,50!!mydate!!mytime2:~0,-2!!idInjection:~0,50!!result!!comm:~0,100! > !fichierTrace!


    ::Copier les fichiers dans l'archive
    ::xcopy /q !fichierTrace! !archive!\%mydate%_%mytime2%\TRSUPIN.txt >nul
    ::xcopy /q !fileToInject! !archive!\%mydate%_%mytime2%\TRSUPIN.txt >nul

    ::Supprimer le fichier de log injection
    ::del !logMaintenance!_!COUNTER!
    ::del !logSuppresion!_!COUNTER!

   )
  endlocal
```

Comment: three questions: did you use setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion, does the directory contain spaces, is it on the same drive. You really need to show a bit more of your code here so we have a general idea of what goes wrong.

Comment: What value does the variable `folderIn` carry?

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is `delayedExpansion`, add this before your commands;

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
```

---

If it is spaces in `folderIn`, add quotes around the variable in your `cd` command;

```
cd "!folderIn!"
```

---

If it is an incomplete path, be sure to complete it like;

```
cd "X:\Example\SubFolder\!folderIn!"
```

---

Combine these as needed, or let us know more insight.

### Edit

---

mis-matched variable names?
try

```
cd "!inFolder!"
```

Comment: Then please include more of your code, and an example of what the variable stores.

Comment: `folderIn` is not defined. `inFolder` is however, is that your error?

Comment: No, it's not. I think it might be something with my computer because I've got an older version of the script, without the loop which worked a few hours ago, and now I have the same error.

Comment: I've just added  the other version

Comment: I've found where the problem was.
Apparently it was because of the comments at the end with "::" . I'm using rem now and I don't have anymore errors.

Comment: Oh that clears things up, you can use `::` as a comment, just not in a `(code block)`, or it will break the order as labels cannot be there.